# Extracting Text from a cell

Tags: excel

I have a search function which works perfectly for searching for Exact Numerical values, However I need to adapt it so it searches for text within a cell and only extracts that text. For example it searches column 7. In column 7 there may be a cell containing the words Interface - HPT, SAS, LPT Ideally I would like to search for the word Interface - HPT then extract Only this text from the cell. I also need the search function to be able to do this for multiple different values. So for example run a search for Interface - HPT 
Interface - SAS and Interface LPT separate from each other. Is this Possible ?

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
Sub InterfaceMacro()

Dim Headers() As String: Headers = _
    Split("Target FMECA,Part I.D,Line I.D,Part No.,Part Name,Failure Mode,Assumed System Effect,Assumed Engine Effect", ",")

    Worksheets.Add().Name = "Interface"
    Dim wsInt As Worksheet: Set wsInt = Sheets("Interface")
    wsInt.Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    wsInt.Cells.Clear

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With wsFHA
        For i = 0 To UBound(Headers)
            .Cells(2, i + 2) = Headers(i)
            .Columns(i + 2).EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Next i
        .Cells(1, 2) = "Interface TABLE"
        .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, UBound(Headers) + 2)).MergeCells = True
        .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, UBound(Headers) + 2)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(2, UBound(Headers) + 2)).Font.Bold = True
    End With

    Dim SourceCell As Range, FirstAdr As String
    Dim RowCounter As Long: RowCounter = 3

    Dim SearchTarget() As String
    SearchTarget = Split("9.1,18.0", ",")

    For i = 0 To UBound(SearchTarget)
        If Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
            For j = 1 To Worksheets.Count - 1
            With Sheets(j)
                Set SourceCell = .Columns(7).Find(SearchTarget(i), LookAt:=xlWhole)
                If Not SourceCell Is Nothing Then
                    FirstAdr = SourceCell.Address
                    Do
                        wsInt.Cells(RowCounter, 2).Value = SearchTarget(i)
                        wsInt.Cells(RowCounter, 3).Value = .Cells(SourceCell.Row, 6).Value
                        wsInt.Cells(RowCounter, 4).Value = .Cells(3, 10).Value
                        wsInt.Cells(RowCounter, 5).Value = .Cells(2, 10).Value
                        wsInt.Cells(RowCounter, 6).Value = .Cells(SourceCell.Row, 2).Value
                        For k = 0 To SourceCell.Row - 1
                            If .Cells(SourceCell.Row - k, 3).Value <> "continued." Then
                                wsFHA.Cells(RowCounter, 7).Value = .Cells(SourceCell.Row - k, 3).Value
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next k
                        wsInt.Cells(RowCounter, 8).Value = .Cells(SourceCell.Row, 14).Value
                        Set SourceCell = .Columns(7).FindNext(SourceCell)
                        RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
                    Loop While Not SourceCell Is Nothing And SourceCell.Address <> FirstAdr
                End If
            End With
            Next j
        End If
    Next i


    End Sub
```

The part I believe needs editing is this section

```
Dim SourceCell As Range, FirstAdr As String
        Dim RowCounter As Long: RowCounter = 3

        Dim SearchTarget() As String
        SearchTarget = Split("9.1,18.0", ",")

        For i = 0 To UBound(SearchTarget)
            If Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
                For j = 1 To Worksheets.Count - 1
                With Sheets(j)
                    Set SourceCell = .Columns(7).Find(SearchTarget(i), LookAt:=xlWhole)
                    If Not SourceCell Is Nothing Then
                        FirstAdr = SourceCell.Address
```

Comment: please share just the part of the code which is relevant for your question. First thought I'd suggest `instr()` or regular expressions, have you tried them?

Comment: I have edited the question in reply to your post. It is basically the part of the code that defines what is being searched for that I need some clarification on. This code works perfectly when searching for multiple numeric values but im looking to adapt it to search and extract certain text values for another project I am working on.

Comment: you can define the array to search the same way as you define it for numbers. To search also part of the cell content you need to change `.Find(SearchTarget(i), LookAt:=xlWhole)` to `.Find(SearchTarget(i), LookAt:=xlPart)`. If this isn't the solution you need please add some example data and desired output to make easier to understand your question.

Comment: thanks, that actually works pretty well for what im looking for it to do.

Comment: Just out of curiosity if the cell contains a formula. would this have an effect on how the search function operates. I.E if the "words" in the cell are actually from a formula would this be a problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the array to search the same way as you define it for numbers.

To search also part of the cell content you need to change `.Find(SearchTarget(i), LookAt:=xlWhole)` to `.Find(SearchTarget(i), LookAt:=xlPart)`.

VBA looks in formulas / results the same way as it works in Find / Replace dialog. (set `.LookIn` to either `xlValues` or `xlFormulas`)

Comment: would I add the . lookin like this `.find(SearchTarget(i), LookAT:=xlPart, lookinxlValues ?`

Comment: @seanbaird: `.find(SearchTarget(i), LookAT:=xlPart, lookin:=xlValues)`